# System.ArgumentNullException when using TextEncodings

Tags: asp.net, exception, encoding, auth0

I have the following lines somewhere in my code

```
    var issuer = "https://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:DOMAIN"] + "/";

    var audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["auth0:CLIENT_ID"];

    var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(
                  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0:CLIENT_SECRET"]);
```

An null exception is thrown in the last statement.  Here is part of the stack trace:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: text]

Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder.Base64UrlTextEncoder.Decode(String text) +99
AuthZero.API.Startup.ConfigureAuthZero(IAppBuilder app) in c:\Users\Abdi\Source\Repos\Auth0-Example\AuthZero.API\Startup.cs:34
AuthZero.API.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in c:\Users\Abdi\Source\Repos\Auth0-Example\AuthZero.API\Startup.cs:21
```

Obviously the TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode is looking for a String parameter, but instead I have another method inside. Not sure why it isn't working as I am copying from another github [repo](https://github.com/tjoudeh/Auth0-Example/blob/master/AuthZero.API/Startup.cs).

Here is my AppSettings which is located the Web.Config [file](https://github.com/tjoudeh/Auth0-Example/blob/master/AuthZero.API/Web.config):

```
   <appSettings>
     <add key="auth0:ClientId" value="gO0K9jkaxegRGRSHcZLuaiaCR3aSnDkH" />
     <add key="auth0:ClientSecret" value="1zvvKpyWGmFdufNldpB2A9xGuKV_YcAk-pxTNa9RnVTjTIhc5a8GVL6pcufM4owV" />
     <add key="auth0:Domain" value="amalexp.auth0.com" />
  </appSettings>
```

---

Okay, I think I fixed the issue by removing `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` and inserting the strings directly instead of looking at the App.Config file. But I got a "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory." error which is another story.

Comment: Debug the program to check what `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0:1zvvKpyWGmFdufNldpB2A9xGuKV_YcAk-pxTNa9RnVTjTIhc5a8GVL6pcufM4owV"]` evaluates to at runtime. By the sounds of it, its `null`.

Comment: You are correct that is evaluates to null, any idea why that is?

Comment: Seems like that setting key doesn't exist in your app settings yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space and an underscore in the setting name in the code, but not in the app.config.

Comment: sorry i made those changes to hide the keys. There are no spaces or underscore in my actual file.